# Apply date filter in date string array of another array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having a collection which holding array of objects which is called as "Fields" and I am having another string array called as "Value" which is inside "Fields" array.

Now I have to filter using date but the value is holding inside Value array.

Please help me to form the query.

The collection object like below,

```json
    {
       "_id" : ObjectId("62aeb8301ed12a14a8873df1"),
       "Fields" : [ 
        {
            "FieldId" : "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b",
            "Value" : [ 
                "test_123"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "fa6745c2-b259-4a3b-8c6f-19eb78fbbbf5",
            "Value" : [ 
                "123"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "2a1be5d0-8fb6-4b06-a253-55337bfe4bcd",
            "Value" : []
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "eed12747-0923-4290-b09c-5a05107f5609",
            "Value" : [ 
                "234234234"
            ]
        },        
        {
            "FieldId" : "fe41d8fb-fa18-4fe5-b047-854403aa4d84",
            "Value" : [ 
                "Irrelevan"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "93e46476-bf2e-44eb-ac73-134403220e9e",
            "Value" : [ 
                "test"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "db434aca-8df3-4caf-bdd7-3ec23252c2c8",
            "Value" : [ 
                "2019-06-16T18:30:00.000Z"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "00df903f-5d59-41c1-a3df-60eeafb77d10",
            "Value" : [ 
                "tewt"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "FieldId" : "e97d0386-cd42-6277-1207-e674c3268cec",
            "Value" : [ 
                "1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "FieldId" : "35e55d27-7d2c-467d-8a88-09ad6c9f5631",
            "Value" : [ 
                "10"
            ]
        }
      ]
     }
```

I am having query like,

```js
    db.getCollection('Table1').find({
    $and:[
        {FieldsDatas:{$elemMatch:{FieldId:'e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b',Value:{$regex:'^mani',$options:'i'}}}},
        {FieldsDatas:{$elemMatch:{FieldId:'e97d0386-cd42-6277-1207-e674c3268cec',Value:{$in:['1','2','1,2']}}}},
        {FieldsDatas:{$elemMatch:{FieldId:'35e55d27-7d2c-467d-8a88-09ad6c9f5631',Value:'10'}}},
        {FieldsDatas:{$elemMatch:{FieldId:'db434aca-8df3-4caf-bdd7-3ec23252c2c8','$first':
            {Value:$gt:[{$toDate:'$this'},Date('2022-06-16')]}
        }}}
    ]})
```

you can see date is available inside Value array "2019-06-16T18:30:00.000Z". we have to apply filter for that field only.

Note : Value array have only one value

$toDate filter is not working and date filter also not working. Please find the below link where it has sample,

https://mongoplayground.net/p/sroaYHWViG2

Please suggest me your answers to resolve this.

Thanks in advance,
Mani

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$map` and `$reduce` to extract the date out from doubly nested array. Use `$convert` to make it a proper date object and use the `onError` option to make other non-date value to be `null`. Finally use `$reduce` again to extract the only date object again and perform `$match` on it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateForFilter": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Fields",
          "as": "f",
          "in": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$$f.Value",
              "initialValue": null,
              "in": {
                "$convert": {
                  "input": "$$this",
                  "to": "date",
                  "onError": null,
                  "onNull": null
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateForFilter": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$dateForFilter",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this",
                  null
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dateForFilter: {
        $lt: ISODate("2022-06-16")
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z1MxZsHKpDg) for your reference.

Comment: Hi @ray, Thanks for your quick response. This query have very bigger. Is there any simple way to do this? Why I am asking, because I can add filters with any dynamic array of values. So it might be multiple match filters. So if it is simple query it will great helpful for me.

Comment: `db.collection.find({
    $and:[
        {Fields:{$elemMatch:{FieldId:'e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b',Value:{$regex:'^mani',$options:'i'}}}},
        {Fields:{$elemMatch:{FieldId:'e97d0386-cd42-6277-1207-e674c3268cec',Value:{$in:['1','2','1,2']}}}}
    ]})`

For an example I can form the query like above how do I append your answer here. I have to filter value along with filter by id so I know the type of column based on id.

Comment: Is this possible to apply filter with out extracting the double nested array?

Comment: @ManiJ I guess not likely. What can be done to shorten the code is squeezing the array processing into one single stage, but that could make the code less readable. The major problem is you have a dynamic, doubly nested structure, which makes the processing complicated. Another thing is you are storing the date and numeric values as string, which are generally considered as anti-pattern. Consider storing them as proper date object or proper numeric value for easier query

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ray, Is there any way to add FieldId filter and extract that Value alone?